# Is there a way to share functions in Zeppelin with a spark interpreter instantiated per note?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-zeppelin

I have searched all the way through the internet and could not find a solution for the following problem:

I am using a spark interpreter in Zeppelin that is instantiated per note. I have it this way because I want to have variables with the same name for different purposes and they will be running simultaneously, so having the interpreter instantiated globally could potentially cause variables to be called from other notebooks.

However, I want to import functions from each notebook from a central source. In this case I want to have an utils notebook with all the functions I want to use, that will feed all the other notebooks with the functions I need, so when I want to change a function, it gets changed for everyone. This option is available in Databricks, but in Zeppelin it is not, at least directly. Either I can choose to share everything from all the notebooks, or to share nothing at all.

Does any of you, by any chance, have a solution for this problem? Ideally I want to call the functions from one zeppelin notebook, but if you find a way to have the functions called in another directory and directly import them to the different notebooks it solves my problem.

Important note: The notebooks are running in a shared IP address, not locally.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `runNote` function as described in [here](https://docs.qubole.com/en/latest/user-guide/notebooks-and-dashboards/notebooks/zep-notebooks/running-notebooks.html)

`z.runNote("<noteid>")` where noteid is the hash after `/notebook/` in the URL

Note that need to *execute* your note first in the current cluster. It does not import it as a library it only connects the interpreter instances.